# Send notification from C# winform application to another user?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2

I have created an aplication using c# winforms and database sql server 2008 R2.

This application will be installed on 10 machines.

Database is installed on server which interacts with all the users.

Now one user(Admin) want to send a notification on button click  to all the 9 users if a particular table in the database is inserted with a record.

And all 9 users will get the notification in the label to "Please update."

Can any body help me with this.

Thanks..

Comment: One approach could be to have the application keep a background thread running which polls the database for new messages every few seconds and notifies the user when there's something new.  Then when the admin wants to send a message the admin's app would just save a message record to the database.

Comment: is there any other approach

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [SqlDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62xk7953.aspx) class to do this, it requires Service Broker, but handles most of it for your automatically; once setup, your application will fire an event when a watched table changes.

Comment: It requires service broker to be running; it performs well, but make sure it will scale properly for you needs if you have many clients connecting to the same server.